# Django code changes not reflecting on production server

Tags: python, django, apache, caching, memcached

I changed a .py file and changes reflected on local dev. server for Django after deleting .pyc. 
The production server does not even have .pyc for this specific file. Tried touching apache wsgi and restarting apache on prod. server but no luck.
Even deleting this .py file makes application work the same. There is memcached installed but I don't have much idea how it caches, there is .git as well and 5 servers are hosting - one main, 4 load balancers.

Regards !

Comment: Sounds like the page is cached somewhere like a reverse proxy

Comment: Can you please elaborate and specify what I can try to clear the caches ?

Comment: I'm no sysadmin so I can't really help you with specifics

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are 100% sure you are looking at the right server you are making the changes to? I know that sounds stupid but, why don't you stop Apache, can you still run the page then? IF you can then you definitely don't have the correct server.

If not, next try reloading Apache (thats different from restarting).

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

If this still does not work then post your Apache setup, if must be looking on the wrong folder to the one your pushing to.

Comment: Thanks... Reload did the magic. Works intermittently, say 8 out of 10 times... Any suggestions how to fix permanently...

Comment: It depends if you are getting an error. Setup logs and check on the times it fails that may give you an idea.

Comment: As mentioned by @Tarilo in a comment to the question, browsers caching static content can sometimes produce this same problem. With me, my changes to the css of my web pages weren't showing up in production. Wasted about 20 minutes looking for problems until Tarilo's comment reminded me to clear the cache which immediately solved the problem. Not the solution in this specific question but it could save another person some time.

Answer (score 2):

You have to restart your server (WSGI, UWSGI or whatever your use on production environment)

Comment: The server has been hard-rebooted, and apache restarted. WSGI has to be restarted too ? Sorry, I don't have much idea about this WSGI thing. Just read it from other similar posts.

Comment: If your hard-reboot your server, you don't need to restart processes. If this doesn't helps you, maybe you also have to clean up *.pyc files in sources directory. But I think it would be enough, if you just hard-reboot.

Comment: Even deleting the .py file doesn't affect. This means it is definitely cached, and there is no .pyc corresponding to this. I even tried find on /

Answer (score 1):

If you use uwsgi as gateway set touch-reload param in uwsgi settings
and you need just

```
$ touch <your-touch-reload-file>
```

in console for reflecting on changes

If you use apache with mod_python or mod_wsgi, you have to restart apache for apply changes

Comment: Using mod_wsgi...
Tried /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
Then /etc/init.d/apache2 start

Still doesn't work :(
Even adding a new URL doesn't work. Definitely being cached somewhere !

Comment: @Levon Can you provide or point me to an example of touch-reloading in uwsgi?