# django code changes not reflecting on the server

Tags: python, django

On my local machine the django app shows all the changes I brought in the code but on the production server the changes are not reflected. Server is a virtualbox with Ubuntu installation, the web server is the one which comes with django installation (I don't know its name).

I have searched several hours, specially this [Django code changes not reflecting on production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770972/django-code-changes-not-reflecting-on-production-server) post was so similar, but nothing in this post helped.

What I have tried so far?

- Restarted the server by "sudo reboot" command.
- Updated the PYTHONPATH with the directory name, as per the instruction of the code I am maintaining. by this: export
  PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/appName"
- Double and triple checked the path, and I am 100% sure that I am editing the right file.
- Deleted the files, but still the server was running.

Comment: "The web server is the one which comes with django installation". Django doesn't come with a web server that can be used in production. You need to understand how your server is set up before trying to debug why it isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that is used in the production, unfortunately. The builtin django web server can be used in the production but not recommended as it is insecure. This server is in a VPN.

Comment: Which command you use to run the server?

Comment: sudo python -m appName.manage runserver 0.0.0.0:80

Comment: It's a year later. How's editing live code on production working out for you?

Answer (score 0):

You must try running your application via gunicorn.

Setup `uwsgi.ini` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/)

Add `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:80 app_name.wsgi:application` to gunicorn conf file.

For setup through nginx and uwsgi: [Check here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Hope this helps.